# Define a Mongoose Schema index (2dsphere) on an optional parameter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, indexing, 2dsphere

I have an user model, which can be of two types : postulant and recruiter.

I want the postulants to have a geolocation field, but not the recruiter, and I have to make them in a single Model.

There's a part of my model :

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    type: {type: String},
    name: {type: String},
    geolocation: {
        name: {type: String},
        type: {type: String, default: 'Point'},
        coordinates: {type: [Number]}
    }
}
)

schema.index({ geolocation: '2dsphere' })
export default mongoose.model('User', schema)
```

My problem is :

When I try to create a 'recruiter', I have an error saying that Mongo failed to index 'geolocation' into a 2dsphere index. And I understand this problem.

I want to index geolocation only if it's not null, so I can create recruiter without saving their location, and create postulants with their location saved.

Can you help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure what the problem was :

I defined :

```
geolocation: {
        name: {type: String},
        type: {type: String, default: 'Point'},
        coordinates: {type: [Number]}
    }
```

The fact is that, with the `default: 'Point'`, I had an geolocation object who was created, with an empty array.
To solve this, I just removed this `default: 'Point'` and the object is not created, so the `schema.index`is not running.